# Obtaining the query string from C# RESTful services

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I use a `Global.asax` file to public my Rest services implemented in C#.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyServiceAPI", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyServiceAPI)));
```

I can access the query string from this file (`Request.queryString()`)

My question is how can I pass this back to the lower layers (implementation) from the `Global.asax`.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Not sure if I understand correclty - if you need to access the query string in lower layers System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url normally helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please add this as a response so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: I have added the comment as a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access the query string in lower layers `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` normally helps.